# Replace a (powerpoint) shape in Excel VBA without changing its position number

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am trying to write code that should automatically replace some shapes in a PowerPoint presentation. The position number of the shapes to replace are assumed known. 
My first idea was to delete the shape, and then add another shape to the slide.

```
sld.Shapes(numShpe).Delete

srcSheet.ChartObjects(chartNum).Copy
sld.Shapes.Paste
```

The problem is that if I want to use this code again, `numShpe` won't be anymore the number of the shape I want to replace. Indeed when using `delete`, shape(n) becomes shape(n-1).
So if there is a way to delete without changing the numbering, there won't be any problem.

Is there any idea you can suggest?

Post 2:

I have tried the Siddharth suggestions. Here is a part of my code:

```
Set sld = pres.Slides(slideNum)
Dim shpeName As String
shpeName = "Picture 15"


Dim shpe As PowerPoint.Shape

Set shpe = sld.Shapes(shpeName)

shpe.Delete

srcSheet.ChartObjects(chartNum).Copy

Set shpe = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=10, link:=msoFalse)

shpe.Name = shpeName
```

when running it, I got the following error (about assignment on line `Set shpe = slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=10, link:=msoFalse)`)

"shapes(unknown member): Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable."

I can't find out where it comes from...

Comment: Instead of using numbers, give them a name and then use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using numbers, give the shape a name and then use that

For example (**Tried And Tested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oPPApp As Object, oPPPrsn As Object
    Dim oPPSlide As Object, oPPShape As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim chartNum As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant file
    FlName = "C:\MyFile.PPTX"

    '~~> Establish an PowerPoint application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oPPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oPPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oPPApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant powerpoint file
    Set oPPPrsn = oPPApp.Presentations.Open(FlName)
    '~~> Change this to the relevant slide which has the shape
    Set oPPSlide = oPPPrsn.Slides(1)
    '~~> This is the shape which will be replaced
    Set oPPShape = oPPSlide.Shapes("MyShape")

    oPPShape.Delete

    chartNum = 1

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartNum).Copy

    Set oPPShape = oPPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=10, Link:=msoFalse)
    oPPShape.Name = "MyShape"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Siddharth. First of all thanks. I tried to do like you suggest. But I got an error on the assignement Set shpe = slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=10, link:=msoFalse). I should write it in another post so that it is more clear.

Comment: I tried your code too, changing just the file name, and I still got an error on the same line. This time, the error is "Automation error" "Unspecified error". I am using office 2010.

Comment: The above code is tried and tested. May I see a sample of your PPT File?

Comment: Finally, after rebooting my computer it works good - No more error. Thanks!